# How to upload files to two different folder

Tags: php, html

I'm having trouble to upload 2 files to 2 different folders.I only able to upload one file to one selected folders.

Here's the screenshot of it :

[image: I manage to upload two files but it was in the same folder.]

Here's the code :

```
<form name="form_id" id="form_id" action="javascript:void(0);" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width:800px; margin-top:20px;">  

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <label class="fieldlabels">Documentation:</label> <br>
            <input type="file" name="vasplus_multiple_files" id="vasplus_multiple_files"  accept="application/pdf" multiple="multiple"/><br>  
            <!--input type="submit" value="Upload" /--><br>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:60%;" id="add_files">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">File Name</th>
                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Status</th>
                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">File Size</th>
                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Action</th>
                  <tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>                     

    </div> 
                            
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br> 
</form>

<br/>

<form name="form_id2" id="form_id2" action="javascript:void(0);" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width:800px; margin-top:20px;">  
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <label class="fieldlabels">Photo:</label> <br>
            <input type="file" name="vasplus_multiple_files2" id="vasplus_multiple_files2" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*"/><br><br>        

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:60%;" id="add_files2">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Photo Name</th>
                      <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Status</th>
                      <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">File Size</th>
                      <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Action</th>
                    <tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>


        </div> 
                            
                        
       <input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br> 

</form>
```

And here's the upload.php code,in the code I just upload to one folder location :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    $vpb_file_name = strip_tags($_FILES['upload_file']['name']); //File Name
    $vpb_file_id = strip_tags($_POST['upload_file_ids']); // File id is gotten from the file name
    $vpb_file_size = $_FILES['upload_file']['size']; // File Size
    $vpb_uploaded_files_location = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/claim_210119/claim_file/document/'; //This is the directory where uploaded files are saved on your server
    $vpb_final_location = $vpb_uploaded_files_location . $vpb_file_name; //Directory to save file plus the file to be saved
    //Without Validation and does not save filenames in the database
    if(move_uploaded_file(strip_tags($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']), $vpb_final_location))
    {
        //Display the file id
        echo $vpb_file_id;
    }
    else
    {
        //Display general system error
        echo 'general_system_error';
    }

}
?>
```

How can I make the uploads in the two different forms to two different folders in my pc.Can anyone help on this?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to save one file in location A and another in location B?

You can simply use the submit button's `name` attribute to identify which form's values come to `PHP` file and then use the desired location.

So add another expression inside if condition like:

```php
if (isset($_POST["form1"])) // name of first form's submit button
{
  // Your desired location
}
else
{
  // Your desired location
}

// Rest of your logic is applicable for any location :)
```

Add `name` attribute in submit buttons in both forms like:

```html
<input type="submit" name="form1" value="Upload" />
```

and

```html
<input type="submit" name="form2" value="Upload" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try following code
if(isset($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
if(!empty($_FILES['vasplus_multiple_files'])){
    //for first form.
    try{
           $vpb_file_name = strip_tags($_FILES['vasplus_multiple_files']['name']); //File Name   
           $vpb_uploaded_files_location = './claim_file/document/'; //This is the directory where uploaded files are saved on your server
           $vpb_final_location = $vpb_uploaded_files_location . $vpb_file_name; //Directory to save file plus the file to be saved
         
           $tmp_file_path = strip_tags($_FILES['vasplus_multiple_files']['tmp_name']);
           //Without Validation and does not save filenames in the database
   
           move_uploaded_file($tmp_file_path, $vpb_final_location);
           echo $vpb_file_name; //Display the file name
enter code here
    }catch(Exception $ex){
           echo $ex->getMessage();  //Display general system error
    } 
}
    //for second form.
      if(!empty($_FILES['vasplus_multiple_files2'])){
    try{ 

           $vpb_file_name_new = strip_tags($_FILES['vasplus_multiple_files2']['name']); //File Name   
           $vpb_uploaded_files_location_new = './claim_file/documentNew/'; //This is the directory where uploaded files are saved on your server
           $vpb_final_location_new = $vpb_uploaded_files_location_new . $vpb_file_name_new; //Directory to save file plus the file to be saved
         
           $tmp_file_path_new = strip_tags($_FILES['vasplus_multiple_files2']['tmp_name']);
           //Without Validation and does not save filenames in the database
   
           move_uploaded_file($tmp_file_path_new, $vpb_final_location_new);
           echo $vpb_file_name_new; //Display the file name
    }catch(Exception $ex){
           echo $ex->getMessage();  //Display general system error
    }
  }
}
```